# Neo4j: numeric property key

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to store a Python dictionary as node key-value pairs in Neo4j, however, it seems that you cannot have an integer as the property key.

```
CREATE (n:label {1: "first_val"})
```

you also cannot pass an integer as a string, which would be a workaround:

```
CREATE (n:label {"1": "first_val"})
```

Is there a way to store an integer as a property key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The naming rules and recommendations docs for node labels, relationship types, property names state that (link [here](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/syntax/naming/#cypher-naming)):

- Must begin with an alphabetic letter.

  - This includes "non-English" characters, such as å, ä, ö, ü etc.
  - If a leading non-alphabetic character is required, use backticks for escaping; e.g. `^n`.
- Can contain numbers, but not as the first character.

  - To illustrate, `1first` is not allowed, whereas `first1` is allowed.
  - If a leading numeric character is required, use backticks for escaping; e.g. `1first`.

That is: you should use backticks for escaping:

```
CREATE (n:label {`1`: "first_val"})
```